# Выборка элементов на jq

Tags: jquery

Как сделать чтобы выбор элемента block был только среди элементов внутри родителя box, а не среди всех элементов box на странице?

```js
jQuery('.block').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
    jQuery('.block').not(this).removeClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.block{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.block.active{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: А разве сейчас не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте метод `siblings()` для поиска сестринских элементов ([документация](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)):

```js
jQuery('.block').click(function(e) {
    jQuery(this).siblings('.block').removeClass('active');
    jQuery(this).addClass('active');
});
```

```css
.box{
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.block{
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 10px;
}

.block.active{
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```